# Consecutive statements on a line in an if statement

Tags: swift, sorting

Getting the problem in an if statement...

```
func sortStudents(students: [Student], byNames: [String] ) -> [Student]{
        var result = [Student]()

        for name in byNames {
            if let students = students.filter{ $0.sName == name}{
                if students.count > 0{
                    result.append(students[0])
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, it would be

```
if let students = students.filter({ $0.sName == name }) { ... }
```

But `filter` doesn't return optional, anyway, so you shouldn't be using `if let` syntax at all.

So you could do:

```
func sortStudents(students: [Student], byNames: [String] ) -> [Student]{
    var result = [Student]()

    for name in byNames {
        let students = students.filter { $0.sName == name }
        if students.count > 0 {
            result.append(students[0])
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: *Theoretically,* `if let students = (students.filter { $0.sName == name }) { ... }` works as well, i.e. you can use the trailing closure syntax if the expression is enclosed in parentheses.